# Split file name and extension from the path in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image

I have the Code snippet shown below

```
string iName = opFile.SafeFileName;
// here iName = Image1.jpg
```

Now, I want the file name and file type as separate strings as

```
string a ="Image1";
string b ="jpg";
```

How to do that, any help appreciated.

Comment: `iName.Split('.')` ?

Comment: Not in some case , i.e `ima.ge.jpg`

Comment: I was waiting for that 14 minutes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check this Microsoft documentation for [`System.IO.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8#methods) class.

- `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(iName);` - will returns filename.
- `Path.GetExtension(iName);` - will returns extension of the file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - if you do not want the "." in the file extension, you will need to remove it as the Path.GetExtension function returns it as the first character in the string from what I recall. (e.g. - Path.GetExtension("SomeFile.jpg") returns ".jpg")